# Change Worksheet after personalized right click option added

Tags: excel

I have the following code that works as expected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton
  Dim currentUPC As String
  Dim currentArticle As String

  
  Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
  If Intersect(Target, Range("C21:C42")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
    Exit Sub
  End If
    
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
    
    currentUPC = ActiveCell.Value
    currentArticle = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
    With cmdBtn
        .Tag = "testBt"
        .Caption = "Goto UPC"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "=gotoUPC(" & currentUPC & ")"
    End With
   
End Sub
```

But the macro it runs is not quite working as planned:

```
Sub gotoUPC(currentUPC As String)
   
    Sheets("UPC Summary").Range("A21").Value = currentUPC
    Worksheets("UPC Summary").Activate
   
End Sub
```

The value in Range A21 updates correctly but it will not activate the worksheet as required.

Any additional thoughts on my method of passing the parameter appreciated @FaneDuru

Any thoughts appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go to the worksheet 'UPC Summary' you could use this.

```
Application.Goto Sheets("UPC Summary").Range("A1"), True
```